How to automate Azure Data Factory (ADF) credential updates from development to production using Azure DevOps?
I'm working with Azure Data Factory (ADF) and need to automate the promotion of credentials (e.g., Linked Service connection strings, secrets) from the development environment to production using Azure DevOps. I want to create a release pipeline that:

Updates credentials automatically in the ADF linked services.
Uses Azure Key Vault to manage sensitive information (like passwords or connection strings).
Promotes credentials from development to production securely without hardcoding them in the pipeline.

What is the best way to achieve this using ARM templates and Azure DevOps? I would also like to understand how to override Key Vault secrets between environments during deployment.
Any guidance or step-by-step examples on how to set up this release pipeline would be appreciated!
What I've tried so far:
I have this setup in DevOps to deploy pipelines.



"I would also like to understand how to override Key Vault secrets between environments during deployment."? Can you clarify what you mean by saying "override Key Vault secrets"? Do you want to override the secrets in Azure KeyVault using the variables in Azure Pipeline or want to override the parameters in the ARM template using the secrets in KeyVault? 2. "Updates credentials automatically in the ADF linked services." - Please clarify in detail. Which specific credential you want to update?


Not sure about your specific configuration of ADF, here is an example for deploying from one env to another.

Config git for your DEV ADF to use Azure repo. See the details from Connect to a Git repository.

Store sensitive information in Azure Key Vault.

Create a release pipeline in Azure DevOps.
For artifact:

Source type: Azure Repo
Default branch: adf_publish


For stages:
Add two stages, one for Dev and another for Prod.

For tasks:

Use Azure Key Vault task to download secrets inside it.

Azure subscription: An ARM service connection to access your Azure Key Vault.
Key vault: Select the Key Vault storing the sensitive information for your current env.

Use ARM template deployment task to deploy your ADF.
Fill in the parameters above Template based on your actual conditions.
Template: Use the Browser Template button to select the template from the artifact. For example, ARMTemplateForFactory.json.
Template parameters: Select your template parameter, ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json.

Override template parameters: Click the three-dot button after "Override template parameters" to override parameters.

You can reference secrets in Azure Key Vault directly in your pipeline using the format $(SecretName), for example, -AzureSqlDatabase1_password $(DB-Secret-Prod) in the screenshot below.
For different env, use different secrets/keyVaults.
If you already linked Azure Key Vault to store sensitive information in ADF, you should parameterize the key vault name and override the key vault here instead of the secrets inside it. Learn about parameters from Parameters in ARM templates.






The above example may not be 100% applicable to you, but the idea of ​​integrating with Azure Key Vault and deploying ADF to different environments is the same. For any credential in the template, parameterize and override it.

Thank you so much for your answer, it helped me a lot in resolving some of the problems.
I have two doubts that may seem a bit silly:
Why do we need to include two stages? If I want to deploy from dev to prod, is one stage enough?
How does this pipeline identify the destination Data Factory? Basically, how does it know where to deploy these changes?
Thank you so much for the support!

Hi @vw96, there is the answer to your question: 1. "If I want to deploy from dev to prod, is one stage enough" - It's enough. Just add one stage to deploy to prod. 2. "How does this pipeline identify the destination Data Factory" - The ADF is also in the ARM template. If you check the screenshot of ARM template deployment task, you will find the first override parameter is the ADF -factoryName $(adf-prod). You can add a variable in the pipeline and read it via $(var) . In my example, the name of my prod ADF is stored in pipeline variable adf-prod.

Thank you for your support. I was able to fix the issues in my pipeline
